# Get value of specific object property in javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

Im pretty new to javascript and would love some help on my problem here. So what I am trying to do is to extract the value of "group" from my object array using the id value. The object array is in the following format: `y = [{"id":id,"group":group, "sid":sid}]`. Have looped through the array as shown below. How do I extract the group value? Thanks!

```
y = [{id:123, group:2, sid:32}];
id = 123

      for (var i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
        if (y[i].id == id) {
        //Get group value for id "123" here

        }
      }
```

Comment: same way you accessed the `id` property

Answer (score 0):

Just use the object that matches your condition (`y[i]`) and refer to the property `group` of it :

```
if (y[i].id == id) {
  var group = y[i].group;
}
```

`group` is a property that is accessible as any property defined in the objects that you are manipulating (as for example : `id` or `sid`)